# Error with Symfony's cache and permissions

Tags: php, symfony, caching

I got this continuous error with cache. Something with permissions but I can't figure what's going on. In my local environment when I go a `php bin/console cache:clear -e=dev` it return me this

```
  [Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Exception\IOException]                                                                                               
  Failed to remove file "/project/var/cache/de~/pools/ORsqbHaOKl/L/K/iZULk48B-k00dzIKC2qg": unlink(/project/var/cache/de~/pools/ORsqbHaOKl/L/K/iZULk48B-k00dzIKC2qg): Permission denied.
```

So I need to make first a `chmod -R 777 var/`, then again the clear cache and it works. But when I run the website it return me

```
Failed to create "/project/var/cache/dev/tcpdf": mkdir(): Permission denied.
```

So I need again to make `chmod -R 777 var/`

In the production server without erasing anything sometimes i get this error

```
Warning: rename(C:\project\var\cache\prod/doctrine/orm/Proxies\__CG__AppBundleEntitySomeEntity.php.5a142ad84e8464.47105642,C:\project\var\cache\prod/doctrine/orm/Proxies\__CG__AppBundleEntitySomeEntity.php): Access is denied. (code: 5)
```

> error in vendor\doctrine\common\lib\Doctrine\Common\Proxy\ProxyGenerator.php
>   (line 309 rename())

```
    $tmpFileName = $fileName . '.' . uniqid('', true);
    file_put_contents($tmpFileName, $proxyCode);
    @chmod($tmpFileName, 0664);
    rename($tmpFileName, $fileName);
}
```

Local environment: debian 9
Production environment: windows server 2008

Comment: 775 is enough! I think it may have to do with the owners of the files, maybe the username:group of the files is not the same as the webserver

Comment: I've noticed to that every time you clear the cache of the development environment, the "writable by all" setting for the directory will be lost. Found no solution yet though.

Comment: @teeyo there is nothing to do with permission. I make 777 as example. This is something with the bin/console that create the permissions. Some folders are created with my own username / group and others with www-data

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to set the var folder permissions as suggested by [this](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/file_permissions.html) symfony article.

Run the following commands in your project directory and you will not come across any permission related issues on cache and logs

```
HTTPDUSER=$(ps axo user,comm | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1)
sudo setfacl -dR -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:$(whoami):rwX var
sudo setfacl -R -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:$(whoami):rwX var
```

Comment: I tried that bu terminan didn't like HTTPDUSER=$(ps axo user,comm | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1)

Comment: Ok. This command is just trying to get the apache/nginx user. Mostly it would be "www-data" if you haven't changed. You can also confirm that in /etc/apache2/envvars. You would see "export APACHE_RUN_USER = <USERNAME>". Once you confirm the apache user come back and run the other two commands. replace $HTTPDUSER with your apache username.

Comment: I figured how to solve it with this answer, but I'll edit some things to make it work in my case

Answer (score 2):

I've just played around with it a bit and noticed that every time you call

```
bin/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

The user of the folder `/prod` will be changed to the user that is executing the call. The scripts deletes the folder and creates a new own, but that will be done be the current user set.

You can stop the script from creating a new folder by using the `--no-warmup` option. With that, I've fixed my problem.

```
bin/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-warmup
```

For that to work you need to fix the current situation once, at best by deleting all folders and files within the `/var/cache` directory.

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer but this does not solve my problem:  $ php bin/console cache:clear --env=dev --no-warmup

                                                                                                          
  [RuntimeException]                                                                                      
  Unable to write in the "/project/var/cache/dev" directory

Comment: @BraianMellor you need to fix your permission for the first time by your self, at best by just deleting the whole `/prod` and `/dev` folder within the `cache` directory.

Comment: Well following your sugest I made this: `chown -R www-data` and `sudo chgrp -R www-data` for every folder inside var (cache, logs, sessions). Then run the websit and the make php bin/console cache:clear --env=dev --no-warmup [UnexpectedValueException] The stream or file "/project/var/logs/dev.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied. The dev.log file is www-data owner.

Comment: @BraianMellor Check the write permission on the `log` folder and files, most likely the write permissions are missing. [Also check the documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/file_permissions.html)

Comment: drwxr-xr-x for logs folder and -rw-r--r--  for dev.log file. What's your suggestion?

Comment: @BraianMellor Can you delete the log files and then start the website again? After that, try to clear the session and then try again.

Comment: The only way that manage to do it is to manually delete the dev, logs and sessions folders and run the website. the `clear:cache` do not work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159504/discussion-between-khorneholy-and-braian-mellor).