# At some point Symfony cache adapter failed to save key

Tags: php, docker, symfony, caching, fpm

I am running a Symfony application on a Docker container with this environment specs:

- Docker base image: `php:8.1.5-fpm`
- PHP: `8.1.5`
- Symfony: `5.4.*`

I am recurrently facing a strange behavior where the Symfony cache adapter is no more able to save data on the filesystem due to permission issue. Here an example of the warning emitted:

```
cache.WARNING: Failed to save key "App%5CController%5CAjaxController" of type array: fopen(/var/www/symfony/var/cache/prod/pools/system/vlNLJCjFzq/d8a651379e96): Failed to open stream: Permission denied {"key":"App%5CController%5CAjaxController","exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): fopen(/var/www/symfony/var/cache/prod/pools/system/vlNLJCjFzq/d8a651379e96): Failed to open stream: Permission denied at /var/www/symfony/vendor/symfony/cache/Traits/FilesystemCommonTrait.php:99)","cache-adapter":"Symfony\\Component\\Cache\\Adapter\\PhpFilesAdapter"} []
```

Indeed when I inspect the `/var/www/symfony/var/cache/prod` file tree I can see that some files / directories like `pools` are owned by`root` whereas they must be owned by `www-data` user:

```
drwxr-xr-x  1 www-data www-data   4096 Apr 13 18:05 .
drwxr-xr-x  1 www-data www-data   4096 Mar 31 09:11 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root        743 Apr 13 18:05 App_KernelProdContainer.php
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root          0 Apr 13 18:05 App_KernelProdContainer.php.lock
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root     314018 Apr 13 18:05 App_KernelProdContainer.php.meta
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root     148907 Apr 13 18:05 App_KernelProdContainer.preload.php
drwxr-xr-x  2 root     root      86016 Apr 13 18:05 Container6ZI03W9
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root      14072 Apr 13 18:05 annotations.map
drwxr-xr-x  3 root     root       4096 Apr 13 18:05 doctrine
drwxr-xr-x  4 root     root       4096 Apr 13 18:05 pools
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data   4096 Apr 13 18:05 translations
drwxr-xr-x 39 www-data www-data   4096 Apr 13 19:17 twig
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data 169603 Apr 13 18:05 url_generating_routes.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  31306 Apr 13 18:05 url_generating_routes.php.meta
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data 181199 Apr 13 18:05 url_matching_routes.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  31306 Apr 13 18:05 url_matching_routes.php.meta
```

What I can guess is that this state is not the original one since:

- I have an explicit command while building the Docker image that creates the `/var/www/symfony/var/cache/prod` directory and gives full ownership to `www-data` to `/var/www/symfony/var` directory.
- When I connect to the container just after its start all files / directories are effectively owned by `www-data`:

```
drwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data   4096 Apr 14 13:39 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data   4096 Mar 31 09:11 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data    743 Apr 14 13:39 App_KernelProdContainer.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data      0 Apr 14 13:39 App_KernelProdContainer.php.lock
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 314018 Apr 14 13:39 App_KernelProdContainer.php.meta
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 148907 Apr 14 13:39 App_KernelProdContainer.preload.php
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data  86016 Apr 14 13:39 Container6ZI03W9
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data  14072 Apr 14 13:39 annotations.map
drwxr-xr-x 3 www-data www-data   4096 Apr 14 13:39 doctrine
drwxr-xr-x 4 www-data www-data   4096 Apr 14 13:39 pools
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 181199 Apr 14 13:39 url_matching_routes.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data  31306 Apr 14 13:39 url_matching_routes.php.meta
```

So this lets me assume that this files have necessarily been modified by the `php-fpm` master process which is the one and only in the container executed with the `root` user.

But why, I have no clue...

Has anyone encountered this behavior before? How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

See the response of Aleem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47414905/error-with-symfonys-cache-and-permissions) for give the right permission to /var:

```
HTTPDUSER=$(ps axo user,comm | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1)
sudo setfacl -dR -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:$(whoami):rwX var
sudo setfacl -R -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:$(whoami):rwX var
```

You can verify in /etc/apache2/envvars if group and user are correctly set to www-data.

Comment: It is true that setting `var/` permissions with `Access Control List` is recommended by the [Symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/file_permissions.html#1-using-acl-on-a-system-that-supports-setfacl-linux-bsd). I don't know why it is better than `chown` but sure I will give it a try.